# What is the purpose of the reverse loop and where is the element being injected to the array

Tags: c, reference

I came across a piece of code that do this:

```
arr = &some_array;
some_placeholder = array_push(arr);

// The loop:
for (i = arr->nelts - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    *((some_pointer *)arr->elts + i) = *((some_pointer *)arr->elts + i - 1);
}
*(some_pointer *)arr->elts = my_item;
```

What is the purpose of the loop?

I do not have a **c** knowledge, and I wonder what is this loops trying to do,
and where is the `my_item` goes inside the array?

Comment: Apparently I get down votes for being curious, and want to learn.

Comment: You provide incomplete code. That basically always gets downvotes. Ideally, a [mcve] is what this site wants.

Comment: The complete code, is huge. And if I would've known how to produce minimal example, I wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place. I provided the lines necessary to my opinion to understand the question. (not only the loop, but the way the array is being copied from, and the assignment part).

Comment: That's said, I would be very happy to know what is missing.

Comment: With "complete" I meant something, which can be copy-pasted to editor and compiled. Sometimes it is justifiable to provide a non-complete snippet, but even then it should be as complete as possible. Like in this case, there are variables without types for no reason.

Comment: I understand. I made the naming of the variables, to give some sense. But the type of `some_pointer` is a whole different thing. which it doesn't seems to matter anyhow. Good day, and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short:

The loop copies each item from index `i - 1` to index `i`.  If the loop was not in reverse order, it would copy first item to every item.

Then it overwrites item at index 0 (now also copied to index 1) with `my_item`.

---

A more readable way to write the loop would be to use array indexing instead of plain pointer arithmetic. This is exactly equal code:

```
for (i = arr->nelts - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    (some_pointer *)arr->elts[i] = (some_pointer *)arr->elts[i-1];
}
(some_pointer *)arr->elts[0] = my_item;
```